# How much money is taken from one day's operation of a bus under the given conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bus operates between Miami International Airport and Miami Beach, $10$ miles away. It makes $20$ round trips per day, carrying $32$ passengers per trip. If the fare each way is $\$11.00$, how much money is taken from one days operation?

I got $\$14,080$. I took twenty times thirty two times twenty two, but now I am questioning whether or not that is right. Is there misleading information in this problem or am I overthinking it?

Comment: You are right. ${}$

Answer (score 1):

I feel that your answer could be the correct answer,

Fare for one trip for one person = $22$

Fare for $32$ passengers $= 22*32= 704$

Total money received from 1 day of operation $= 704*20= $14,080$

(*I feel that the 10 mile distance is just to confuse you)